# Are .fon (bitmap font) files needed in Windows XP?

Tags: windows-xp, performance, fonts

I'm trying to make a minimal XP installation for low-end machines, and I want to remove anything that could slow the system down.

I've heard many fonts installed slow down the boot process, so I'd like to keep the number of them to a minimum, and I'm seeing a lot of **.fon** files everywhere.

Is it safe to delete all/some (which?) of the **.fon** font files? They don't look like they're of much use, but maybe one of them is the terminal font?

Comment: They're indeed just bitmap fonts. I'd keep the default cmd window font at least, although I don't know what that is. Deleting the rest should be safe for the most part.

Comment: @JohnChadwick Problem is, I don't know what that font is. Indeed the only place where I see a bitmap font is in the cmd.exe terminal emulator window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is my minimalist list for XP   This was to clean the registry itself, before I put my font stack back in, so I am not totally sure about it.  It is english only, and was for limited use of the computer , like I did not use servers and terminals.
the ariel narrow is not part of the originals.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts]
"Fixedsys (Set #6)"="vgafix.fon"
"Roman (All res)"="ROMAN.FON"
"Script (All res)"="SCRIPT.FON"
"Modern (All res)"="MODERN.FON"
"Small Fonts (VGA res)"="SMALLE.FON"
"WST_Engl (All res)"="wst_engl.FON"
"Courier 10,12,15 (VGA res)"="COURE.FON"
"Terminal"="cga40woa.fon"
"Arial (TrueType)"="ARIAL.TTF"
"Arial Bold (TrueType)"="ARIALBD.TTF"
"Arial Narrow (TrueType)"="ARIALN.TTF"
"Courier New (TrueType)"="COUR.TTF"
"Courier New Bold (TrueType)"="COURBD.TTF"
"Times New Roman (TrueType)"="TIMES.TTF"
"Verdana (TrueType)"="verdana.TTF"
"Verdana Bold (TrueType)"="verdanab.TTF"
"Franklin Gothic Medium (TrueType)"="Framd.TTF"
"Tahoma Bold (TrueType)"="tahomabd.TTF"
"MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (VGA res)"="SSERIFE.FON"
"MS Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24 (VGA res)"="SERIFE.FON"
"Tahoma (TrueType)"="TAHOMA.TTF"
"Microsoft Sans Serif (TrueType)"="MICROSS.TTF"
"MS-DOS CP 437"="dosapp.fon"
"Terminal (US) (Set #6)"="vgaoem.fon"
"System (Set #6)"="vgasys.fon"
"WST_Engl"="wst_engl.fon"
```

I see all the other .Fon stuff in there that your talking about now. And i cannot be positive that I was seeing them all at that time, being hidden.

Comment: I'm curious, there's a few missing, such as italics, I think you don't miss them, do you?

Comment: In XP anything could be bent :-) into italics, or Bolded, so I tossed them and let the programs bend & bold them. Hard to remember, this was done soo long ago.

Comment: Well, I guess people really don't notice that kind of thing (I think I'd do, since I'm a little pedant with fonts), and this is not for my use anyway. Given a choice, probably normal people prefer a PC that runs fast and looks good from a distance.

Comment: In the end, this is how it looks: http://i.imgur.com/Gl77i.png (I kept some such as Impact so as not to break the look and feel of naive websites that use that crapfront).

Answer (score 1):

".fon" files contain bitmap fonts. These fonts were used by earlier DOS-based Windows (Windows 3.1 era). They are included in recent Windows releases for backwards compatibility purposes.

**If you aren't using any super-old applications that rely on these fonts, you don't need them.** The Windows GUI has not relied on them for many, many years.

Comment: With that said, I don't know if it's worth the trouble. TrueType and OpenType fonts take far more RAM to load than bitmap fonts. I'd focus on removing as many .ttf's and .otf's as possible - and those only if your systems are really tight on RAM.

Comment: Gabe: well, I'm trying to make a setup that works for PCs on the range of 512-768 MB of RAM. Since I'll only have to do this one time, I wanted to know if it can be done safely.

Comment: Do you know if the CMD console emulator doesn't need them too?

Comment: If you are planning to run console applications in DOS emulation mode, I'd leave them in place. However, cmd.exe does use TTF fonts if bitmap fonts aren't available.

Comment: The more I think about it, a system with 512MB of RAM can handle a few TTFs in RAM. I think you might be over-optimizing here.

Comment: Well, I'm shaving off as much as I can in order to leave in more visible stuff (such as ClearType, Themes, etc). I want it to feel responsive, even if it's installed on a low-end laptop.

Comment: I removed the files from an XP VM and saw no issues.

Answer (score 0):

Many of them seem to be useless, but accortding to [the last post here post](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=831499), Windows XP expect these `.fon` files to be there:

- `SERIFE.FON`
- `SSERIFE.FON`
- `MODERN.FON`
- `COURE.FON`
- `ROMAN.FON`
- `SCRIPT.FON`
- `SMALLE.FON`
- `SYMBOLE.FON`